# How to keep X months from oldest date in R

Tags: r

I have a datatable (dt) with the following elements, an id of an Item ,the date and  stock on that day.

```
 ID        date             Stock
193sd      2016-03-23        12
238ds      2016-04-20         1
238ds      2017-07-20         1
238ds      2018-07-20         1
193sd      2017-09-12         1
193sd      2018-09-12         1
193sd      2018-03-12         1
193sd      2018-05-12         1
```

To keep 5 months from oldest day I do the following:

```
dt$date = as.Date(dt$date, origin="1899-12-30")

months5= aux[, .SD[date>= min(date) %m-% months(5)], by = ID]
ID        date             Stock
193sd      2016-03-23        12
238ds      2016-04-20         1
238ds      2017-07-20         1
238ds      2018-07-20         1
193sd      2017-09-12         1
193sd      2018-09-12         1
193sd      2018-03-12         1
193sd      2018-05-12         1
```

But the resulting table (months5) has same values which exceed the 5 months,

Please tell me what I am doing wrong in my function.

UPDATE!:
running the following code as Gregor suggeste

```
months5= dt[, .SD[date<= min(date) %m+% months(5)], by = ID]
    ID        date             Stock
    193sd      2016-03-23        12
    238ds      2016-04-20         1
    193sd      2018-05-12         1
```

But still between **2016-03-23** and  **2018-05-12**  in ID **193sd** there are more than 5 months.

Comment: Seems like you need `%m+%` not `%m-%`. Of course all the months come after min date *minus* 5 months. And maybe you want `<=` not `>=`, from your text I'm not sure if you want to keep or remove dates in the first 5 months from min date.

Comment: Is there a missing `library` call in here?

Comment: `library(lubridate); library(data.table)` both definitely needed.

Comment: Thanks, Gregor. Both of your suggestion were needed. Had never encountered either of `%m-% or`%m+%`. Looked like a foreign language.

Comment: I'm voting to close as typo. I think the problem is completely solved by changing `%m-%` to `%m+%`. It *might* also require changing `>=` to `<=`, but I'm less sure of that.

Comment: @Gregor check the update

Comment: I can't replicate your update. Using your input data `dt[, .SD[date <= min(date) %m+% months(5)], by = ID]` returns the expected two rows for me, not 3 like you show in your question. I'd suggesting restarting your R session and trying again.

Comment: (For testing purposes, I'd also recommend you use an example data set where more than one row *should* be kept in at least one group)

Comment: I copied the test data and tested and it returns 2 rows, I dont't why I got that result before thank you so much Gregor!